# Dear "Name here" Vs. Mr./Mrs. "Name here" Vs. Hi "Name here" Vs. Hello "Name here"

Tags: differences

Vs.

Mr./Mrs. "Name here",

Vs.

Hi "Name here",

Vs.

Hello "Name here"

What is better to start email or written letter?

Comment: Please do not ask subjective or proof-reading questions on this list. And when you post a question make the context clear. Writing to your mates allows a different style from writing to a prospective employer.

Comment: @David In case you were unaware, you are giving feedback on a seven year old question.

Comment: @MetaEd — oops. Killing time on the phone. Worthwhile comment to anyone reading it as it's come up again.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603546/2085).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify, so I'm assuming you don't know these people and are writing a form letter, or spam.

You don't know if it's Mr. or Mrs. (or Ms.), so that's out.

You're not familiar with them to the point of friendship, so "hi" is not a good choice either.

"Hello" sounds a little vague and robotic, the way someone who didn't speak the language very well might sound.

"Dear ..." sounds like the right tone use with someone you don't know. And use the full name: "Dear Douglas Robinson," etc.

If my supposition is incorrect, and you do know the people you're emailing pretty well, a simple "Hi" will suffice.

Comment: OK. Thanks for reply. I'm intending to spam. What if I know the person's Gender only, don't know him personally . Then Should I use Mr. or Miss/Ms. or here also "Hi Name" is a better option.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Safer to use no gender specifier. Just use Dear and the full name.